# Can't scraping a javascript page even with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to scrap some data from a js web site but even with selenium it still can't reach it.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("-no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("-disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)

driver.get('http://mc164.boxtoplay.com:65248')
print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
```

The output:

```
b'<html lang="en"><head>\n\n\t<title>Minecraft Dynamic Map</title>\n\n\t<meta charset="utf-8">\n\t<meta name="keywords" content="minecraft, map, dynamic">\n\t<meta name="description" content="Minecraft Dynamic Map">\n\t<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">\n\t<!-- These 2 lines make us fullscreen on apple mobile products - remove if you don\'t like that -->\n\t<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">\n\t<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">\t\n\n\t<link rel="icon" href="images/dynmap.ico" type="image/ico">\n\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\t<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leaflet.css?_=3.3.2-696">\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n    <!-- FOr source debug on leaflet \t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet-src.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script> -->\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custommarker.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dynmaputils.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sidebarutils.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\n\t<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/embedded.css" media="screen" />-->\n\t<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/standalone.css?_=3.3.2-696" media="screen">\n\t<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dynmap_style.css?_=3.3.2-696" media="screen">\n\t<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/override.css" media="screen" /> -->\n\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="version.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.json.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/minecraft.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hdmap.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\t<script type="text/javascript" src="standalone/config.js?_=3.3.2-696"></script>\n\n\t<script type="text/javascript">\n\t\t\t$(document).ready(function() {\n\t\t\t\twindow.dynmap = new DynMap($.extend({\n\t\t\t\t\tcontainer: $(\'#mcmap\')\n\t\t\t\t}, config));\n\t\t\t});\n\t</script>\n\n</head>\n<body>\n<noscript>\n For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript.\n Here are the <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">\n instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser</a>.\n</noscript>\n\n\t<div id="mcmap"></div>\n\n</body></html>'
```

Comment: What output did you want?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan not one who say `For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript. Here are the http://www.enable-javascript.com/ instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browse`

Answer (score 0):

I think, javascript is not executed while in headless mode. You can try without headleass mode.

if the app is developed using javascript. you can try any javascript framework to capture the data.

Comment: I tried without headless mode and its still doesnt work.